# Appcelerator building/compiling a module How-To

Tags: appcelerator

I'm fairly new to modules in Appcelerator. I want to incorporate a module within my mobile app. Following is the link:

https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.millennialmedia

How do I build the .zip file I need to install the module in my project?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download the zip files of this module from here:

**[Ti.Millennial](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.millennialmedia/releases)**

If you need to build for specific Titanium version, then look at **[Complete Guidelines to create Titanium Modules](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile)**

Note that you do not need to rebuild the modules for **iOS**, you can directly use the Releases at first link. You only need to build modules for **Android** in case you are using **Ti SDK 6** or above.

Comment: Thanks. But now I seem to be getting the following error when running my project with this module. Installing and configuring the module in my project is completed.

Comment: Correction for previous comment:


Thanks. I have installed and configured the module in my project. But now I seem to be getting the following error when running my project with this module. 

[ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED ** [ERROR] : The following build commands failed: [ERROR] : Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<APP NAME>.app/<APP NAME> normal x86_64 [ERROR] : (1 failure)

Comment: This is for IOS using Ti SDK 6.0.1

Comment: Can you post that error in Question because I can't read the complete error due to comments character limitations?

Comment: [ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED ** [ERROR] : The following build commands failed: [ERROR] : Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<APP NAME>.app/<APP NAME> normal x86_64 [ERROR] :

Comment: this is not complete error log, please put actual log or share a screenshot

Comment: Heres a link to an image showing the error message: http://www.bistech.ca/error.png

Comment: Now you can do 2 steps to trace this issue:
*1-* Delete *build* and *Resources* folders from your project folder and then Clean the project & run again.

*2*- Run the app in *Console's Trace mode* which can tell you where this error is coming from.

I suggest to do step 1 first.

Comment: I get the same error as before doing step 1 or step 2. Here is the trace log: http://www.bistech.ca/consolelogtrace.rtf

Comment: This error is coming from module itself. So you can either try to resolve it or just wait until someone fixes it and release new distribution file.